# Sharing an simple executable file for multiple people?

Tags: c#

*Beginner level question*

Scenario: Have simple string cocantation tool, that I might expand later on. I'm interesting in keeping updates and "upgrades to it" as time progresses. They have access to the shared drive.

1. Share one executable and they just have shortcuts to it? Multiple users using it? (might have issues with personalization that I could setup later on.)
2. Have them copy over the setup file to their individual computer and install individually?
3. If applicable, please let me know HOW I could publish updates simply with the "publish tool." Is it fairly straightforward and updates them telling them updates are available?

I'm a beginner so a little help or links to beginner level explantions on this would help.

Comment: @Sheldon, if you like ocdecio's answer then please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that executing files on a shared/widely accessible drive is probably not the best idea. How many people are we talking about?

Since you only have 7-8 people in your group, maybe the best solution here is to simply make the setup executable available on your shared drive, that way your users can have access to the newest version of your tool whenever they like and can install it on their machine at their leisure.

sure there are more elegant solutions here, but they may take too much hassle to implement for such a small group, especially if you are not getting paid to distribute this tool to your peers.

Sometimes the simplest approach is best, and I don't usually condone manual efforts, but in this case it may work best for you.

Good luck,
-Robert

Comment: 7-8 people. I'm not in the IT department, so I'm just helping out with a small summary tool, like a form, for combining notes and documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Look into [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: Agreed, but it's only convenient if you have an IIS running.

Comment: ClickOnce can be run from file shares on servers, doesn't need to use IIS.

Comment: this seems exactly what I was looking for, great source link with tons of info